# Order of records not maintained by executeBatch in Java

Tags: java, performance, oop, jdbc

I am inserting number of records in database its inserting correctly, but the order of the records not maintained. So is there any solution to solve this problem except ORDER BY clause.

Comment: create an auto increment field

Comment: Could you state where that forms a problem? In order to get more leads. For instance with `statement.getGeneratedKeys()` you could retrieve all autoincr keys.

Comment: If you mean the order of records as returned by `select * from your_table` then this order is not fixed unless `order by` is used. If you mean any other order of how data is arranged on disk -- let your DBMS decide this and do not tinker with that even if you can.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing like order of the records in a database. When using a SELECT without ORDER BY, the database returns the rows in an arbitrary order.

If you're **unlucky** enough, it returns them in the insertion order. Everything's fine... until some day a table compaction or whatever happens and the order is gone.

Never rely on it.

Comment: and this has nothing to do with java, oop, performance or jdbc, but with the basics of relational databases.